# Best data structure for the following use case

Tags: data-structures

My use case is to apply filters on multiple levels. Think it of as a tree structure with 2 levels only ( for now, my use case includes 2 levels only but intended solution should be around the possibility of having more than 2 levels ) .

```
  *-----------*  ( Level 1 ) 
 / \         / \
/   \       /   \
*    *     *     * (level 2)
```

1. A user can either accept or reject rules at level 1 or level 2.
2. If user accepts or rejects a rule on level 1, then the level as well as all its children should inherit the same property which means they will also be accepted or rejected as well.
3. User can add exceptions. for example, as per above point, if he rejects a rule at level 1 then its children will also get rejected. But, user have the option to specifically mark a children as accepted. These are called exceptions.

I want a data structure which should be able to store this information efficiently and given thousands of separate entries, I should be able to filter data on the basis of user preference of acceptance.

size of level 1 is in thousands and every member of level 1 in turn can have thousands of children.

**Examples -** 
lets consider a problem where I have thousand people from 2 countries, US and UK and I want to filter people according to user requirements. consider user have multiple options on multiple levels like this.

```
             US--------------------------UK  ( Level 1 ) 
             / \                         / \
            /   \                       /   \
           /     \                     /     \
          /       \                   /       \
        florida  texas             london     Manchester
         /\         |\              /\          /\
        /  \        | \            /  \        /  \
       /    \       |  \          /    \      /    \
     Male  Female   M   F        M      F    M      F
```

Eg1 - User says remove all people in US. 
So while traversing the list of people, I will remove all people where country==US

Eg2 - User says remove all people of US from the list but people of texas should not be removed.

Eg3 - User says all people of US should be included except males of texas.

So What is the best data structure to store these kinds of rules and apply it on a list to get people according to user's preference.

Just to add to it , There can be thousand of countries and thousands of cities .

**If you can suggest a data structure for two levels, even that would be great.**

Comment: While the size of each level appears to be huge, are there many levels? Also, why do the levels matter in particular? Would it be possible to design it so that if the user accepts or rejects a rule, it is automatically moved to the top level (where there could be an "accepted" top and a "rejected" top)?

Comment: A concrete example with a half dozen or so rules would really help in understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple list with multiple indexes. That is, you have a list of all people regardless of what country they're in.

Then, you decide which properties you want to use for filters. You've mentioned country, state, city, and gender. So you have four hash maps.

1. country name, (hash set of people)
2. state name, (hash set of people)
3. city name, (hash set of people)
4. gender, (hash set of people)

So if you want to select all the males who live in the U.S. state called Texas, you just intersect the lists. That is:

- Get the set of people who live in the U.S.
- Intersect with the set of people who live in Texas.
- Intersect with the set of males.

(Although in this case you can probably optimize the above by noting that everybody who lives in Texas also lives in the U.S., and eliminate the first intersection.)

Anyway, using this technique you can have any number of selection criteria.

If you have `k` selection criteria, then worst case running time is proportional to `k * n`, where `n` is the total number of people in your list. Average runtime complexity should be much better. If you order your intersections based on the number of entries in the hash set, you'll quickly reduce the running time. In the above case, for example, you'd first select the number of people who live in Texas, which cuts down your search space considerably. Then intersect with U.S., and finally by gender.

Space complexity is O(n*k) for the indexes. That is, there will be one entry in every hash map for every person.